# Please check my partial derivative of function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, regression, regression-analysis

Please check my solution + help me with the partial derivation with respect to $\beta_2$

$$Q = \sum(y_i-\beta_1-\beta_2^x)^2$$

$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \beta_1} = 2\sum(y_i-\beta_1-\beta_2^x)\cdot(-1) = 2\left(-\sum y_i + \beta_1 + \beta_2^x\right) \text{ ?}$$

$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \beta_2} = 2\sum(y_i-\beta_1-\beta_2^x)\cdot(\text{?})$$

Thanks

Comment: I think you want $2(\Sigma -y_i+\beta_1+\beta_2^x)$ for the last part of the first partial derivative. It looks like you just moved the minus sign a bit too far. For the second one, just use the chain rule like you did in the first.

Comment: I don't know, what is chain rule, could you please help me?

Comment: The chain rule just says that $\frac{d f(g(x))}{d x}=f'(g(x))*g'(x)$. The same idea applies to partial derivatives. So the (?) in the second partial derivative should be $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_2} (y_i-\beta_1-\beta_2^x)$.

Comment: OK and please what to do after? I want to get a system of normal equations. Do I have to multiply those 2 brackets in the second partial derivative?

Comment: I am affraid, this would be complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that what you want to minimize is $$Q = \sum(y_i-\beta_1-\beta_2^{x_i})^2$$ So, $$\frac{dQ}{d\beta_1}=2\sum(y_i-\beta_1-\beta_2^{x_i})\times \frac d{d\beta_1}(y_i-\beta_1-\beta_2^{x_i})=-2\sum(y_i-\beta_1-\beta_2^{x_i})\tag 1$$ $$\frac{dQ}{d\beta_2}=2\sum(y_i-\beta_1-\beta_2^{x_i})\times \frac d{d\beta_2}(y_i-\beta_1-\beta_2^{x_i})=-2\sum(y_i-\beta_1-\beta_2^{x_i})x_i \beta_2^{x_i-1}\tag 2$$ From $(1)$ you could eliminate $\beta_1$ and then $(2)$ reduces to a nonlinear equation in $\beta_2$; you will need a numerical method to solve it.